# Memory leakage in using `ggplot` on large binned datasets

Tags: r, memory, ggplot2, memory-leaks, data.table

I am making various `ggplot`s on a very large dataset (much larger than the examples). I created a binning function on both x- and y-axes to enable plotting of such large dataset.

In the following example, the `memory.size()` is recorded at the start. Then the large dataset is simulated as `dt`. `dt`'s `x2` is plotted against `x1` with binning. Plotting is repeated with different subsets of `dt`. The size of the ploted object is checked by `object.size()` and stored. After the plotting objects have been created, `rm(dt)` is executed, followed by a double `gc()`. At this point, `memory.size()` is recorded again. At the end, the `memory.size()` at the end is compared to that at the beginning and printed.

In view of the small size of the plotted object, it is expected that the `memory.size()` at the end should be similar to that at the beginning. **But no.** `memory.size()` **does not go down anymore until I restart a new R session**.

---

**REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE**

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

# The binning function
# x = column name for x-axis (character)
# y = column name for y-axis (character)
# xNItv = Number of bin for x-axis
# yNItv = Number of bin for y-axis
# Value: A binned data.table
tab_by_bin_idxy <- function(dt, x, y, xNItv, yNItv) {
  #Binning
  xBreaks = dt[, seq(min(get(x), na.rm = T), max(get(x), na.rm = T), length.out = xNItv + 1)]
  yBreaks = dt[, seq(min(get(y), na.rm = T), max(get(y), na.rm = T), length.out = yNItv + 1)]
  xbinCode = dt[, .bincode(get(x), breaks = xBreaks, include.lowest = T)]
  xbinMid = sapply(seq(xNItv), function(i) {return(mean(xBreaks[c(i, i+1)]))})[xbinCode]
  ybinCode = dt[, .bincode(get(y), breaks = yBreaks, include.lowest = T)]
  ybinMid = sapply(seq(yNItv), function(i) {return(mean(yBreaks[c(i, i+1)]))})[ybinCode]
  #Creating table
  tab_match = CJ(xbinCode = seq(xNItv), ybinCode = seq(yNItv))
  tab_plot = data.table(xbinCode, xbinMid, ybinCode, ybinMid)[
    tab_match, .(xbinMid = xbinMid[1], ybinMid = ybinMid[1], N = .N), keyby = .EACHI, on = c("xbinCode", "ybinCode")
    ]
  #Returning table
  return(tab_plot)
}

before.mem.size <- memory.size()

# Simulation of dataset
nrow <- 6e5
ncol <- 60
dt <- do.call(data.table, lapply(seq(ncol), function(i) {return(runif(nrow))}) %>% set_names(paste0("x", seq(ncol))))

# Graph plotting
dummyEnv <- new.env()
with(dummyEnv, {
  fcn <- function(tab) {
    binned.dt <- tab_by_bin_idxy(dt = tab, x = "x1", y = "x2", xNItv = 50, yNItv = 50)
    plot <- ggplot(binned.dt, aes(x = xbinMid, y = ybinMid)) + geom_point(aes(size = N))
    return(plot)
  }
  lst_plots <- list(
    plot1 = fcn(dt),
    plot2 = fcn(dt[x1 <= 0.7]),
    plot3 = fcn(dt[x5 <= 0.3])
  )
  assign("size.of.plots", object.size(lst_plots), envir = .GlobalEnv)
})
rm(dummyEnv)

# After use, remove and clean up of dataset
rm(dt)
gc();gc()
after.mem.size <- memory.size()

# Memory reports
print(paste0("before.mem.size = ", before.mem.size))
print(paste0("after.mem.size = ", after.mem.size))
print(paste0("plot.objs.size = ", size.of.plots / 1000000))
```

---

I have tried the following modifications to the code:

- Inside `fcn`, removing `ggplot` and returning a `NULL` instead of a plot object: The memory leakage is totally gone. But this is not a solution. I need the plot.
- The less plots requested / less columns / less rows passed to `fcn`, the less is the memory leakage.
- Memory leakage also exists if I do not make any subset and make only one plot object (In the examples, I plotted 3).
- After the process, even after I call `rm(list = ls())`, the memory is still non-recoverable.

I wish to know why this happens and how to get rid of it without compromising my need to do binned plots and subset `dt` to make different plots.

Thanks for attention!

Comment: Add `with(dummyEnv, rm(list = ls()))` before removing the environment.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, the suggestion does help to mitigate the inflation in memory used, but memory leakage still occurs at large especially when the data size is big. Is there any other possible sources of leakage?

Comment: I would be more careful with calling something "memory leak". It's not easy to investigate this as you have (i) use of environments, (ii) a package object that has some special behavior regarding memory, (iii) two other packages in your example. My suggestion would be to not create `dummyEnv`.

Comment: It might well be that you have found a bug in R or data.table but right now I can't confirm this and can't see which one.

Comment: Agree that it is not necessarily memory leak. Not creating `dummyEnv` does not help but intensify the increase in memory usage. I suppose it is something in how `ggplot` handle the dataset... Thank you for helping