# R: deleting ggplot2 object does not free space? Possible memory leakage?

Tags: r, ggplot2, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I notice that when trying to remove a `ggplot2` object from the user workspace, there is still a  lot of memory used!? In the example below, deleting a pseudo ggplot call using a 400MB dataset still leaves 400MB used. This seems to happen in particular when the data used in the `ggplot2` call is directly read from file.

Is this expected behavior, or could that be a memory leakage Hadley talks about in [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html)? And how can I effectively clear the memory (`gc()` won't help)?

Note that this is possibly related to [Memory leakage in using `ggplot` on large binned datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53312860/memory-leakage-in-using-ggplot-on-large-binned-datasets), but that post never received an answer.

Thanks!

```r
pryr::mem_used()
path <- tempfile() 
if(!file.exists(path)){
  saveRDS(as.data.frame(matrix(1:1e08, ncol=5)), path)
}

## memory leak
pryr::mem_used()
#> 34.9 MB
p1 <- ggplot2::ggplot(readr::read_rds(path), ggplot2::aes(V1))
rm(p1)
invisible(gc())
pryr::mem_used()
#> 447 MB
ls()
#> [1] "path"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `ggplot` tracks the last plot created in a cache in the package namespace. It can be retrieved by `ggplot2::last_plot()` and is there so functions like `ggsave()` can work without you having to explicitly pass the plot to the function. You can clear that out with

```
ggplot2::set_last_plot(NULL)
```

So for example

```
pryr::mem_used()
p1 <- ggplot2::ggplot(readr::read_rds(path), ggplot2::aes(V1))
rm(p1)
ggplot2::set_last_plot(NULL)
invisible(gc())
pryr::mem_used()
```

The cache is set anytime you call `ggplot()` or when a ggplot object is printed. It only stores the most recent value.

Comment: Are you saying I should run that line ex-ante, before the ggplot() call?  I still get the same result!? And how wold I proceed  ex-post anyway? Thanks!

Comment: You would run that after the `rm(p1)` otherwise the value that's stored in `p1` will still also be stored in the ggplot2 cache.

Comment: awesome! Was there a more general way to find out that culprit was object `".last_plot"`, in `environment(ggplot2:::.store$get)`? The `ls()` call did not expose it :-( Thanks!